# PowerShell server crashed while modifying big .xml file

Tags: performance, powershell

Well as the title states i made a PowerShell script that had such a horrible performance that it overextended the server ressources and crashed it.

The script reads an entire.xml file and appends a text at the beginning and at the end of the file. Also it changes the name of the file accroding to what is located in my *filename.txt*.

The .xml files are around 500 MB big and have over 4.7 million rows. Is there a way, that i don't have to read the entire file but not loose information?

```
function start-jobhere([scriptblock]$block){
start-job -argumentlist (get-location),$block { set-location $args[0];  invoke-expression $args[1] }
}

$handler_button1_Click= { 
    Try{ 
    $job3 = start-jobhere {
    #Text that should be at filebeginning
    @('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ids:ControlInfo>
    <ids:ObjectFormat>CSV</ids:ObjectFormat>
    <ids:SeparatorForCSV>;</ids:SeparatorForCSV>
    </ids:ControlInfo>

    <ids:BatchDeltaUntil></ids:BatchDeltaUntil>
    </ids:BatchInfo>
    </ids:Header>
    <ids:Body>'
    ) + (get-content ZUB_Lokalisation.xml) | set-content ZUB_Lokalisation.xml

    #Text that should be at file end
    Add-Content ZUB_Lokalisation.xml -Value "</ids:Body>`n</ids:SimpleOperation>"

    #Information that goes into the header of the file but has to be extracted from the filename inside a .txt
    $filename = Select-String filename.txt -Pattern "Lokalisation"
    $nameoffile = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($filename)
    $split = $nameoffile.split('_')
    $finalid = $split[5]
    $content = Get-Content ZUB_Lokalisation.xml
    $content[8] = '     <ids:BatchInfo ids:BatchID="{0}">' -f $finalid
    $content | Set-Content ZUB_Lokalisation.xml

    #Rename the file
    Rename-Item ZUB_Lokalisation.xml -NewName $filename}
    }catch [System.Exception]{zeigen
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("ZUB_LOK_ERROR", "ERROR")}
    }

    Get-Job | Wait-Job | Where State -eq "Running"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create files containing the start and end fragments that you want.

Then run this in a dos window or batch file:

```
COPY StartFile.TXT + YourXMLFile.TXT + EndFile.TXT OutputFile.TXT
```

This sticks the three files together and saves them as OutputFile.TXT

Comment: note that the copy command can be run within a powershell script also